# Bash script for 'apt-get update' with automatically insert password

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, expect

I want make shell script to start `sudo apt-get update`, automatically insert password for `sudo` and automatically hit enter key.

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
expect "[sudo] password for username: "
send "password"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do with

```
#!/bin/bash
echo password | sudo -S apt-get update
```

From `man sudo` and from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty#4327123)

> `-S`, `--stdin`
>                    Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password
>                    from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
>                    The password must be followed by a newline character.

If your password has special characters then use single quotes around the password like `echo 'p@ssowrd'`.

Comment: you'll need to add proper quotation for it to work if the password has special characters in it. i.e. `echo "password"`

Comment: This works, but I would warn you, that it is easy for an intruder to find the password, when you have it in clear text in a shellscript like this.

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea, using `expect` is the right tool. However, your syntax is wrong. Try the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

#some instructions ....

#the <<-EOD ... EOD syntax is called a "heredoc" and allows to send multiple instructions to a command
expect <<-EOD
    #process we monitor
    spawn sudo apt-get update
    #when the monitored process displays the string "[sudo] password for username:" ...
    expect "[sudo] password for username:"
    #... we send it the string "password" followed by the enter key ("\r") 
    send "password\r"
#we exit our expect block
EOD
```